# How do I convert my stopwatch time to a time?

Tags: javascript

The question may be a little confusing so let me clarify a bit more. I am doing a stop watch so when you start then stop it logs your time. I put that time into an array. When I try to do things like Math.min(array) or Math.max(array) I got NaN (not a number). The stop watch time for example is like 00:00:15.91. Obviously that doesn’t register as a legit number, is there a way to get around this?

In more simpler words: I put a “time” (like 00:00:15.91) into an array, is there a way to still retrieve the largest number or smallest number?

I’m doing this all in javascript, no libraries.

Note: I believe I don’t need to show my code for this, but if you need any, I will be happy to provide it.

```
else{
        let displayTime = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds + "." + displayMilliseconds;
        let intTime = displayHours + displayMinutes + displaySeconds + displayMilliseconds;
        let times = document.getElementById("times");
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        status = "stopped";

        if (status = "stopped") {
            times.innerHTML += displayTime + "<img src='https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/xbox-x.png'/><br/>";
            allTimes.push(Number(intTime));


            if (allTimes.length == "0") {
                document.getElementById("bestTime").innerHTML = "none";
                document.getElementById("worstTime").innerHTML = "none";
                document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = "none";
                document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = "none";

            }

            if (allTimes.length != "0") {
                document.getElementById("bestTime").innerHTML = Math.min(...allTimes);
            }

        }

    }
```

edit: I added my code

Comment: Just remove the colons and convert to an int

Comment: @kevino I'm sure I could help you but you need to clarify some things. 1. What exactly does the array look like? `["00:00:15.91"]`? 2. Tell me what you want the 'largest' & 'smallest' number to be of this example. P.s. showing code would help and I'd suggest putting it in the question in case someone tries to shut it for that reason!

Comment: @tonitone120, I have an array,  let  allTimes = [];  Then I push the time, say 00:00:00:50, using allTimes(Number(intTime)); intTime is just the time form the stopwatch. Say we have times 00:00:00:50 and 00:00:00:60. The first time would be the smallest, and second time would the biggest

Comment: @kevino If you put all code in the question I'm sure I'd be able to help. Give me a shout when you do

Comment: @NotZack, is there a way to convert the time that was pushed into the array back to the time format of 00:00:00:00 when you display the value again?

Comment: @kevino why wouldn't there be?

Comment: @kevino It's quite a tricky task so you're going to need to post all the code if you want someone to give you a solution otherwise it runs the risk of getting shut-down

Comment: @tonitone120, I added my code, but I think all I need to do from here is figure out how to get it back into format... you can take a look if you want though.

Comment: Don’t store a formatted string, store a time. Format it later.

Comment: I'm very confused on how to format the number when I retrieve it from the array, any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You can find min and max values ​​by comparing string values. Is type conversion necessary?

```
const list = ['00:00:23.90', '01:00:00.00', '00:00:23.89', '00:01:00.00']
list.sort()

const min = list(0)              // -> "00:00:23.89"
const max = list(list.length-1)  // -> "01:00:00.00"
```